# What's the different using SideEffect and not using it in JetpackCompose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I try to understand [SideEffect](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#sideeffect-publish) of Jetpack Compose.

Other than the official document, I find 3 other reference

- https://jorgecastillo.dev/jetpack-compose-effect-handlers
- https://www.section.io/engineering-education/side-effects-and-effects-handling-in-jetpack-compose/
- https://medium.com/@umairkhalid786/jetpack-compose-side-effects-sideeffect-1e9995b6d423

I'm am still confused. My simple question as below

What's the difference if I do this with `SideEffect`

```
var i = 0
@Composable
fun MyComposable(){
    Button(onClick = {}){
        Text(text = "Click")
    }
    SideEffect { i++ }
}
```

and without `SideEffect`

```
var i = 0
@Composable
fun MyComposable(){
    Button(onClick = {}){
        Text(text = "Click")
    }
    i++
}
```

**Code example from https://www.section.io/engineering-education/side-effects-and-effects-handling-in-jetpack-compose/**

Is there a way the `i++` is still triggered in one case but not the other?
How can I create a way to experiment with that?

Comment: Going through this codelab it will help you how side effects work: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-advanced-state-side-effects#0

Comment: From the code example I think this sums it up the difference : "The code inside the SideEffect block will be executed upon a successful composition. If the composition fails, the code will not be executed." - A better contrived example explcitly showing a failed and successful compostition would have been better to differentiate how this works in practise.

Comment: How can I trigger a failed composition @Mark?

Comment: That is why I didn't post an answer. I understand the "why" just its very opaque as to "how" composition can fail - is this just a runtime error or something else, this is not explained?  A lot of articles just provide similar examples reiterating the documentation. As the documentation doesn't offer transparency I can only assume thats why none of the blog posts offer meaningful examples.  Unrelated post but shows an example of unsuccessful composition whilst testing : https://stackoverflow.com/q/68284586/4252352

Answer (score 7):

The `SideEffect` function is a scope of code triggered outside of the Compose Function. I found a way to differentiate them.

If I run it as below

```
@Composable
fun TrySideEffect() {
    var timer by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Text("Time $timer")
    }

    Thread.sleep(1000)
    timer++
}
```

The above code will only show `0`. The `timer++` has no impact, as it was changed while it is being composed, given it's part of the composable function.

However, if we use `SideEffect` as shown below, given it is not part of the compose function, the `timer++` will trigger this, and this will make the composable function recompose again and again (Given `SideEffect` is being called on each Composable). This will make the Text show 0, 1, 2, 3, 4...

```
@Composable
fun TrySideEffect() {
    var timer by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Text("Time $timer")
    }

    SideEffect {
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        timer++
    }
}
```

**Additional Info**

To make it a little interesting, if I put on the below code, then the text will display 0, 2, 4, 6 ... (given the first `++timer` will happen without composing, and the `++timer` that happen in the `SideEffect` will trigger it)

```
@Composable
fun TrySideEffect() {
    var timer by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Text("Time $timer")
    }

    SideEffect {
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        timer++
    }

    Thread.sleep(1000)
    timer++
}
```

Another interesting note, comparing `SideEffect` with `LaunchEffect`

If we use `LaunchEffect`, the number will only increment once, i.e. from 0 to 1. This is because unlike `SideEffect`, `LaunchEffect` only triggered on the first recomposition, and not change on the subsequent recomposition (unless we change the `key1` value, so it will be triggered upon change of `key1` value.).

```
@Composable
fun TrySideEffect() {
    var timer by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Text("Time $timer")
    }

    LaunchEffect(key1 = Unit) {
        delay(1000) // or Thread.sleep(1000)
        timer++
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Elye! While trying your first example about SideEffect, I have came across with weird behaviour which is not related to Side Effects but I wanted to check with you. If I use the `Text("Time $timer")` as an item inside LazyColumn recomposition only happens one time and SideEffect was triggered one time but it is recomposed many time when it is inside `Box`. Do you have any idea why it is happening this way ?

Answer (score 1):

To simply put, a SideEffect will make sure whatever is in the block will be triggered after all `remember` components' `onRemembered()` are called. This will make sure the block inside a SideEffect will get the most updated values.

Let's take a look at some examples. Here's a simple example that simply shows a Text :

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Counter(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var counter by remember { mutableIntStateOf(1) }
    Text(text = "Counter = $counter")
    Log.d("TAG", "BEGIN : Counter = $counter")
    counter++
    Log.d("TAG", "END : Counter = $counter")
}
```

If we run this code, we will get the following output :

```bash
BEGIN : counter = 1
END : counter = 2
```

However, this will not trigger recomposition. So you can tell that when you do modification like this, it just act like any function, they will be called sequentially.

Now, if we place `counter++` into a **SideEffect** :

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Counter(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var counter by remember { mutableIntStateOf(1) }
    Text(text = "Counter = $counter")
    Log.d("TAG", "BEGIN : Counter = $counter")
    SideEffect { counter++ }
    Log.d("TAG", "END : Counter = $counter")
}
```

We will get a different result :

```bash
BEGIN : counter = 1
END : counter = 1
```

What's more important is that this **will trigger** recomposition. If we didn't add a limit to `counter` inside SideEffect, you will see the number keep on increasing until it reaches `Int.MAX_VALUE` and crash.

If we wrap the second Log into a SideEffect, then we would get the same result as the first try :

```bash
BEGIN : counter = 1
END : counter = 2
```

So you can see the different between calling in and outside of a SideEffect.

---

Now, let's dive into the source code to get a better understanding.

A **SideEffect** is similar to `remember`, however it will be stored as a **Operation.SideEffect** and not **Operation.Remember** :

```kotlin
// Operation.kt
object SideEffect : Operation(objects = 1) {
    inline val Effect get() = ObjectParameter<() -> Unit>(0)

    override fun objectParamName(parameter: ObjectParameter<*>) = when (parameter) {
        Effect -> "effect"
        else -> super.objectParamName(parameter)
    }
    override fun OperationArgContainer.execute(
        applier: Applier<*>,
        slots: SlotWriter,
        rememberManager: RememberManager
    ) {
        rememberManager.sideEffect(getObject(Effect))
    }
}
```

Upon calling `SideEffect {}`, a Operation.SideEffect will be stored inside a `sideEffects: MutableListOf<() -> Unit>()` in **RememberEventDispatcher** :

```kotlin
// Composition.kt
private class RememberEventDispatcher(
    private val abandoning: MutableSet<RememberObserver>
) : RememberManager {
    // ...
    override fun sideEffect(effect: () -> Unit) {
        sideEffects += effect
    }
    // ...
}
```

The SideEffect operator will be triggered in `CompositionImpl.applyChangesInLocked(ChangeList)` after dispatching all remember observers :

```kotlin
manager.dispatchRememberObservers()
manager.dispatchSideEffects()
```

If you were to do any modifications outside of SideEffect, it will happen before `applyChangesInLocked` is called.

---

Next, let's take a look at the differences between calling `counter++` outside and inside a SideEffect.

If we tried to modify `counter` outside a SideEffect, we will find `candidate.snapshotId == id` is `true` in the following code, which will avoid `snapshot.recordModified(state)` being triggered. This will also avoid recomposition to occur due to the change in `counter` :

```kotlin
internal fun <T : StateRecord> T.overwritableRecord(
    state: StateObject,
    snapshot: Snapshot,
    candidate: T
): T {
    if (snapshot.readOnly) {
        // If the snapshot is read-only, use the snapshot recordModified to report it.
        snapshot.recordModified(state)
    }
    val id = snapshot.id

    if (candidate.snapshotId == id) return candidate

    val newData = sync { newOverwritableRecordLocked(state) }
    newData.snapshotId = id

    snapshot.recordModified(state)

    return newData
}
```

However, if we modify it inside a SideEffect, then `candidate.snapshotId == id` will return false. This will record the modification, which at the end will trigger recomposition to occur.

As for why `candidate.snapshotId == id` have different result, all I can say is that's how internal takes care of it.