# What does "pending composition has not been applied" exception mean and how can it be avoided?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, illegalstateexception

I have a working application, but sometimes, for reasons unknown to me, the application crashes with this message:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: pending composition has not been applied

I can't find information anywhere about the occurrence of this exception, and I also don't understand how it can be avoided.

Edit #1: After some research and testing, I found out that this exception is thrown when I quickly switch between tabs in BottomNavigation (tabs contain LazyColumn)

Comment: It's hard to help you without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I haven't found much on the internet, but first of all I'd check on lazy views like `LazyColumn` - try scrolling them out a lot. If this don't help, try commenting out parts of your application one by one to localize it. It's probably a Compose bug, but to fix it the maintainers needs to have an sample to reproduce it.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Thanks for advice, I'll try to find the reason, as soon as I do, I'll supplement the question

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I supplemented the question, but I don't know which code I should provide (and should I do this at all)

Comment: If you have code to reproduce it regularly, I suggest you [filing an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128) including a sample project and device model/Android version. I was able to find kind of [similar issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195860509), but the exception is different so I don't think it's related.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72331245/9795103 might help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since I don't have enough reputation to write a comment I will write it here. Maybe it helps you

I got a same error today. And if I started debugging and I was putting lot of logging rows into my code to understand what exactly causes this issue. And I figured it out what for me caused this error. There was actual problem in my code that threw exception (array index out of bounds), but it seems that somewhere recomposition catches this actual error and throws more generic error.

Simplified my code looked like this

```
val items = myViewModel.items.collectAsState().value
val focusRequesters = myViewModel.focusRequesters.collectAsState().value
LazyColumn() {
    items(items = items) { item ->
        // When I added new item then I got error in this line, 
        // because I forgot to add new focusRequester when I was adding new item. 
        // so it was actually array index out of bounds error
        val focusRequester = focusRequesters[item.position]
        ...
        // Code to show item
    }
    item {
         AddItemButton(myViewModel)
    }
}
```

And actual error that it show me in the log was this generic error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.courtesy.test, PID: 27394
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: pending composition has not been applied
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.drainPendingModificationsForCompositionLocked(Composition.kt:530)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:567)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:811)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$CompositionContextImpl.composeInitial$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3583)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:503)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcomposeInto(SubcomposeLayout.kt:408)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:383)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:374)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:363)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$Scope.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:648)
        at androidx.compose.material.ScaffoldKt$ScaffoldLayout$1$1$1.invoke(Scaffold.kt:316)
        at androidx.compose.material.ScaffoldKt$ScaffoldLayout$1$1$1.invoke(Scaffold.kt:243)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:68)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$createMeasurePolicy$1$measure$1.placeChildren(SubcomposeLayout.kt:527)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:980)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:965)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2063)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:112)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:52)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.layoutChildren$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:965)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.onNodePlaced$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:950)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerPlaceable.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeOuterWrapper-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:158)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.access$placeOuterWrapper-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:28)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$placeAt$1.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:146)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$placeAt$1.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:145)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2063)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:112)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutModifierSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:59)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:145)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.replace(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:170)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.replace$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:838)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:262)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.access$remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:36)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.measureAndLayout(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:201)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onMeasure(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:773)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.internalOnMeasure$ui_release(ComposeView.android.kt:298)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onMeasure(ComposeView.android.kt:285)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:145)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:747)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3397)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2228)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2486)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

So at least for me this error was thrown when actual error happened during recomposition. Of course it would be nice if it would show me the actual error instead of this generic error.

Answer (score 5):

For future reference, I once came across this issue when I typed `remember` wrongly as `rememberSavable`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while having a `setContent` to tell the fragment I will be doing compose from that point, and adding down in the composable tree a Composable to handle maps -> `GoogleMap`.

The problem was I forgot to add the `API_KEY` that maps needed, so the exception thrown was caught during recomposition, and that led to that error to be displayed.

So I guess if you are having this problem check if the recomposition is shadowing the real error. How?

Try to move the composable is responsable for throwing that generic error up in the hierarchy as much as possible just to see the real error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening to me because I have my TabRows indicator TabPosition set to TabPosition[lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex], can't figure out what the solution is yet.

But I essentially want the Indicator to update with the lazy list scrolling visible items

Answer (score 0):

So for me the issue was that I was using two times `setContent` for a `ComposeView`

Example

I was using this

```
composeView.setContet {
 composeView.setContent { ... return@setContent }
}
```

instead I needed to just use one

```
composeView.setContent { ... return@setContent }
```